# Very Difficult Error

Tags: java, android

```
package com.heinrichreimersoftware.materialintro.app;

import android.support.annotation.StringRes;
import android.view.View;

public interface ButtonCtaFragment {
    View.OnClickListener getButtonCtaClickListener();

    /**
     * Note: you must either define a {@link String} or a {@link StringRes} label
     */
    String getButtonCtaLabel();

    /**
     * Note: you must either define a {@link String} or a {@link StringRes} label
     */
    @StringRes
    int getButtonCtaLabelRes();
}
```

This is class where i have  problem:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. >
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/heinrichreimersoftware/materialintro/app/ButtonCtaFragment.class

How can i fix this?

Comment: have you done a `gradle clean`? I see this sometimes when I have stale cached classfiles.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says:

> duplicate entry

There are two possibilities that might be causing this issue:

1. You have `com.heinrichreimersoftware.materialintro` project as a dependency as well as a module/some other module using this dependency
2. You might have two dependencies directly/indirectly calling this `com.heinrichreimersoftware.materialintro` library

I suggest checking all dependencies and modules for solving this issue.

If found in dependencies in `build.gradle`, remove it from any **one** using

> ```
> {
> exclude group: 'com.heinrichreimersoftware', module: 'material-intro'
> }
> ```

Hope it helps!